# Failed to connect the repository Bitbucket with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I want to use Jenkins tool with Bitbucket, to automate the build after each commit.
I created a new Job in Jenkins, but when I put the URL repository from Bitbucket(clone project from Bitbucket) an error appear as the following picture [image]

I want to know what's the problem and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The error reads

> Failed to connect to repository: ... returned status code 128 ... Repository not found

This tells us that Jenkins can't find your git repo by the URL you provided. Looking at the URL, I don't think that's a valid Bitbucket one. Go to your Bitbucket repo, get the URL (you can click on the `Clone` tab and then pick the `HTTP` option and then get the git repo link) and then paste that in the Jenkins URL section. Then it should find your repo.

Comment: That exactly what i did, but i just replace the repository name by dotes "....."

Comment: @Lina my bad. Is your repo closed or open?

Comment: My repo is open, I think this problem due to Proxy server because when i add Credentials another error appear as the following "Failed to connect to repository : Failed to create http proxy uri"

Comment: That's a good guess. Are you able to connect some other repo that's not behind the proxy?